# GeoShape not storing lat/lng

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In ElasticSearch 5 I'm making a property:

```
    var prop = new Property
        {
            Id = page.Id,
            GeoLocation =
                new PointGeoShape(
                    new GeoCoordinate((double) geoPoint.Latitude, (double) geoPoint.Longitude))
        };
```

With a definition of:

```
    public class Property
    {
        [Number]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [GeoShape]
        public PointGeoShape GeoLocation { get; set; }
   }
```

When it's being sent to elastic it's got a type of point, and the lat and lng are both doubles.

However when it inserts into elastic and I get it back it looks like:

```
"GeoLocation": {
    "coordinates": [
      {
        "s": -1,
        "e": -2,
        "c": [
          7,
          9,
          0,
          2,
          8,
          9,
          9,
          0,
          2,
          1,
          3,
          0,
          3,
          2,
          5,
          5,
          7
        ]
      },
      {
        "s": 1,
        "e": 1,
        "c": [
          5,
          1,
          5,
          2,
          6,
          5,
          2,
          0,
          3,
          7,
          4,
          7,
          1,
          9,
          8,
          3
        ]
      }
    ],
    "type": "point"
```

Comment: Did you explicitly map the `Property` POCO in the index e.g. use automapping to map the POCO when creating the index or afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to postman 'prettify', when I checked the raw response it was correct.